# Issues creating sequences while looping through a database link

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to loop through sequences through a database link which I am doing fine. The issue I am getting is ORA-00933 "SQL command not properly ended". If I remove the min value from execute immediate it works perfectly fine. Whats wrong with my syntax?

This is my code:

```
Declare 
    CURSOR seqe IS 
        select sequence_name, min_value from dba_sequences@mylink
BEGIN 
    For i in seqe LOOP 
        execute immediate 'create sequence '||i.sequence_name|| ' min_value ' ||i.min_value; 
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no underscore in [MINVALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-SEQUENCE.html#GUID-E9C78A8C-615A-4757-B2A8-5E6EFB130571)